# Laravel 7.x hosting problem in shared host

Tags: php, laravel, web, error-handling, web-development-server

I am trying to host a laravel project on a shared host. but my project is not running. 
[please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdXvz.png)

I have checked in error log. and it returns the following error message

[25-Apr-2020 14:02:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /home/devcornx/public_html/aweerapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Enumerable.php on line 11

My server php version is 7.4. and json is enabled. please see the following image [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV6OW.png)

Please, Help me. i am totally messed up with this.

Comment: Please, check phpinfo () output via browser. This is the best way to check that json module is loaded.

Comment: @writ3it thank you. i will check

Comment: Server version php update and file permission change. Hope it will help

Comment: Have you run `composer install` ?

Comment: @MdSajolMahmud  Please, let me know if json extesnion exists in the output. If not, problem is occuring in hosting configuration / hosting tools. BUT if it json extension is loaded, I will investigate this case deeper.